# PL/SQL handling multiple notfound exptions +constraint violations

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a pl/sql related question.
Assuming I have quite a long procedurę which has some INSERTS,SELECTS and all.

Is there a way that when one of the selects gets an error I'll know exactly which one?

Let's say I have

```
PROCEDURE processRequests IS
P_ID numer;
P_NAME varchar2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT NAME into P_NAME FROM users WHERE ID=P_ID;
SELECT NAME into P_NAME FROM users WHERE ID2=P_ID;
INSERT INTO users (ID,ID2,NAME)values(1,2,'Joe');

END;
```

I would like to know when the first and second select return an error and update it in an error log table, also some if there are constaints like foreign key, primary key, I'd like to be able to catch those errors.

I've tried using the not_found exception but then I'm not able to know where the error is.

Any tips?

Best Regards
Steven James

Comment: These are the very basics of PL/SQL. If you read any book or Exceptions part of Oracle documentation you will know. This is the very first thing you should do before asking. There are tons of videos on this also. Look at the Practically Perfect PL/SQL with Steven Feuerstein channel on youtube, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to mkuligowski's answer, if you have a very long block and you always want to exit after an exception, a lightweight alternative is to use a section marker to figure out where the exception happened.

```
PROCEDURE processRequests IS
    P_ID numer;
    P_NAME varchar2(20);
    P_SECTION varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    P_SECTION := 'first select';
    SELECT NAME into P_NAME FROM users WHERE ID=P_ID;
    P_SECTION := 'second select';
    SELECT NAME into P_NAME FROM users WHERE ID2=P_ID;
    P_SECTION := 'first insert';
    INSERT INTO users (ID,ID2,NAME)values(1,2,'Joe');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error in section: ' || p_section);
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    raise;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap each query with `BEGIN END` block and handle error in `EXCEPTION WHEN` block. For select statements you can use `NO_DATA_FOUND` and  `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` when you want to prevent from unique constraint vialotions

So the structure of the code, more or less will looks like:

```
BEGIN
--...
  BEGIN
    SELECT NAME into P_NAME FROM users WHERE ID=P_ID;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  -- handle error
  END;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (ID,ID2,NAME) values(1,2,'Joe');
  EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  -- handle error
  END;
  --...
  END;
```